# How to wrap custom tag around {^{datepicker /}} and pass all props

Tags: datepicker, jsviews, custom-tags

I'd like to create a custom tag, containing a datepicker control. How can I pass all properties from the custom tag to the datepicker control?

**The custom tag should look like this:**

```
{^{mycustomdatepicker 
            aDate
            label="Date"
            dataFormat="yy-mm-dd" 
            dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"
            _showOn="button"
            _buttonImageOnly= true
            _buttonText= "Choose middle date"
 /}}
```

**The template for the custom tag like this**

```
<div>Caption: ~tagCtx.props.label</div>
{^{datepicker /}}
```

How do I pass **all** props thru to the datepicker control at once?

Note: I know, I could pass each prop on it's own, e.g.:

```
{^{datepicker dateFormat= ~tagCtx.props.dateFormat _showOn=~tagCtx.props._showOn ... /}}
```

Comment: Did my reply below work for you? If so, can you "accept" it. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is to have your custom tag derive from the `{{datepicker}}` tag:

```
mycustomdatepicker: {
    baseTag: "datepicker", 
    ...
```

See [Specifying tag inheritance: the baseTag option](https://www.jsviews.com/#tagsapi@basetag), and [Custom datepicker tags](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/datepicker/formats@custom).

Then, on your derived tag you can add additional UI by overriding the default template:

```
mycustomdatepicker: {
    baseTag: "datepicker", 
    template: "<div>Caption: {^{:~tagCtx.props.label}}</div>"
    + "{^{include tmpl=#content/}}..."
}
```

See [Rendering wrapped block content](https://www.jsviews.com/#tagsapi@wrapping), and [this sample](https://www.jsviews.com/#tags@tmplblock-sample).

By following that pattern you don't need to pass props and parameters through to a wrapped `{{datapicker}}`. The `{^{include tmpl=#content/}}` will render as the original datepicker did, but can have additional rendered content before and after...

It is also possible to use a render method for your derived tag, rather than overriding the template, along the lines of:

```
mycustomdatepicker: {
    baseTag: "datepicker", 
    render: function(date) {
        return "<div>Caption: " + this.tagCtx.props.label + "</div>"
        + this.tagCtx.render(date) + "...";
    }
}
```

See [this sample](https://www.jsviews.com/#tags@renderblock-sample)